# c# создание копии реестра и последующая работа с ней

Tags: c#, wpf, реестр

Здравствуйте.
Я пишу обучающую игру по дисциплине защита информации. Один из уровней должен обучить студента тому, что такое реестр windows и где там что хранится. Но на компьютерах кафедры естественно реестр заблокирован от изменения. 
Мне необходимо сделать окно, подобное regedit но которое бы обращалось не к реальному реестру windows а к его копии. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать подобное наиболее простым способом.

Программа пишется на C# с использованием WPF

Comment: Поковыряйте класс Microsoft.Win32.Registry из сборки mscorlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте свою собственную копию реестра или скачайте с Интернета. Потом вы сможете загрузить её из файла как описано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894909/load-registry-hive-from-c-sharp-fails).

Answer (score 0):

Вот кусочек кода для работы с реестром. Само дерево веток и ключей реестра выводиться в TreeView.

```
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainTreeView.Items.Clear();

        // открыть ветку в определённом разделе
        RegistryKey[] baseKey = new RegistryKey[]
            {
                Registry.LocalMachine,
                Registry.CurrentUser,
                Registry.ClassesRoot,
                Registry.CurrentConfig,
//                    Registry.DynData,
                Registry.Users,
                Registry.PerformanceData
            };

        // получить 
        foreach (RegistryKey itemKey in baseKey)
        {
            TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();

            // назначить обработчик разворачивания узла дерева
            item.Expanded += Item_Expanded;

            // сохранить информацию о диске в пункте дерева
            item.Tag = itemKey;

            // текст пункта
            item.Header = itemKey.Name;

            // добавить пустой элемент для возможности развернуть узел
            item.Items.Add("*");

            mainTreeView.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private void Item_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // получить ссылку на разворачиваемый пункт
        TreeViewItem parentItem = (TreeViewItem)e.OriginalSource;

        // очистить старые дочерние элементы
        parentItem.Items.Clear();

        RegistryKey current = null;
        if (parentItem.Tag is RegistryKey)
        {
            // получить 
            current = (RegistryKey)parentItem.Tag;
        }

        try
        {
            // получить подпапки текущей папки
            foreach (string subDir in current?.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                // создать для каждой подпапки отдельный узел дерева
                TreeViewItem newItem = new TreeViewItem();
                RegistryKey new_subkey = current.OpenSubKey(subDir, false);
                newItem.Tag = new_subkey;
                newItem.Header = new_subkey.Name.Replace(current.Name, "");
                newItem.Items.Add("*");

                //                    // включение поддержки Drag-n-Drop
                //                    newItem.AllowDrop = true;
                //                    newItem.DragEnter += NewItem_DragEnter;
                //                    newItem.Drop += NewItem_Drop;
                newItem.PreviewMouseDown += NewItem_MouseDown;

                parentItem.Items.Add(newItem);
            }
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
```